# Symfony2 + Doctrine MongoDB ODM - Nesting level too deep when flush()

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine, odm

I have a problem with Symfony2 and Doctrine2 ODM (mongoDB). I'm trying to persist an object to  my collection called 'Status'. It is a very simple object with absolutely no reference and just one property called 'name'. Here is the code of my Status document class.

```
<?php
namespace Site\BlablaBundle\Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;
/**
 * Status
 *
 * @MongoDB\Document(repositoryClass="Site\BlablaBundle\Repository\StatusRepository")
 */
class Status
{
/**
 * @MongoDB\Id(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @MongoDB\String
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return id $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return self
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string $name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

}

When I try to persist a Status object from an EventListener or from my Controller, I got an issue that I cannot fix.

```
<?php
$status = new Status();
$status->setName('Hello');
$documentManager->persist($status);
$documentManager->flush();
```

When the flush() method is executed I got this error :

( ! ) Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in C:\wamp\www\symfony\vendor\doctrine\mongodb\lib\Doctrine\MongoDB\Cursor.php on line 483

The strangest part of this problem is that my Status object is stored in the database BUT this error is raised causing my code to crash. I just don't know how to solve it...

If anyone has encountered this problem and knows how to fix it, it will be very helpful :)

Thanks !

Comment: Most likely there are some other components or documents involved with the `flush()` and your code above is not what actually causes the error. Is there something more that you could tell us about the use case and the application?

Answer (score 0):

It s a php configuration error : you are using through symfony too much in deep function like $this->function1->function2.....function100

This is not neccesarly you code but take in count that all symfony is oriented object ...

To fix this , you should raise you nested values limit in php.ini then restart apache

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! I see the problem... I raised my max_input_nesting_level parameter inside my php.ini (the one used by Apache, not PHP CLI) and restarted Apache, phpinfo() tells the max_input_nesting_level value is updated, but unfortunately  the error is still raised...

Maybe there's another parameter to edit ?

Thanks !